# MS Word remove the Header and footer margins not working

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I am trying to make heading-letter but no matter what can't remove margins from header and footer.

[image: one]

Changing margins to `0`

[image: two]

Returning error (even by clicking `ignore` margins in image 1 still exist)

[image: three]

**Any idea how to remove those margins in print for good?**

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the header and footer have been set, if they are set, set the distance from the header and footer to the page margin to 0.

[image]

In general, the printer preset margins will leave room.

Setting the margin as zero in word does not mean that the margin of the printer is physical zero.

Comment: thanks, those settings are 0 as well :/ but i think there has to be a way to fix that right? i mean you look at every company headdingletter there is no space in their paper.

Comment: @mafortis: company letters are made with different technology. Constant parts are printed in a press / printing machine and only text is printed with a normal printer

Answer (score 0):

For left and right, you do not want to change the margins, but the indents. Margins are a section property while indents are paragraph level formatting. You may have noticed that when you changed the margin in your header, it changed in the body as well. **Change the left and right indent settings in your header and footer *styles*.** You would want negative indents to undo the margins set for the section.

For example, my letterhead has a left margin of 1.58" and a right margin of 1.25" so I would set the paragraph indents to -1.58" and-1.25" to go from page edge to page edge.

[image]

[image]

You can also insert a textbox in a header or footer that goes outside *any* of the margins. It can even extend past the edge of the page!

**One thing you should be aware of is that many printers will not print to the edge of paper.** There is nothing that Word can do about that. This is especially true of the top and bottom edge. The printer manufacturer reserves that space for paper handling.

Comment: Here is a link to the best page on how to set up letterhead in Word. It does not address your exact question but may give you other ideas that will help with your project. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm

Comment: thank you I'll try your solutions to see if they work.

Comment: If you need to work outside top and bottom margins, be sure to try the textboxes. Again, those cannot override limitations set in the printer driver by the printer manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a limitation of your printer, it simply might not be able to print without borders

Comment: thank you maybe you're right